Is there a PHP MSK Client library that supports using IAM roles
trying to use php client to connect to a MSK kafka cluster setup to use IAM roles
All code I can find shows the need for a username and password in the SASL config, is there a way to use IAM role assigned to ECS or EC2 instance?
sample
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\Glue\GlueClient;
use Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
use SimpleKafkaClient\Producer;
use SimpleKafkaClient\Configuration;
// Set up AWS credentials and region
$provider = CredentialProvider::defaultProvider();
$region = 'us-west-2'; // Change to your region
// Initialize Glue client
$glueClient = new GlueClient([
    'region' => $region,
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => $provider
]);
// Retrieve schema from Glue Schema Registry
$schemaName = 'your-schema-name'; // Change to your schema name
$registryName = 'your-registry-name'; // Change to your registry name
try {
    $result = $glueClient->getSchemaVersion([
        'SchemaId' => [
            'SchemaName' => $schemaName,
            'RegistryName' => $registryName,
        ],
        'SchemaVersionNumber' => [
            'LatestVersion' => true,
        ],
    ]);
    $schemaDefinition = $result['SchemaDefinition'];
} catch (AwsException $e) {
    echo "Error retrieving schema: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit(1);
}
// Set up Kafka configuration
$conf = new Configuration();
$conf->set('metadata.broker.list', 'localhost:9092'); // Change to your broker list
$conf->set('sasl.mechanisms', 'AWS_MSK_IAM');
$conf->set('security.protocol', 'SASL_SSL');
// $conf->set('sasl.username', ''); // AWS IAM username
// $conf->set('sasl.password', ''); // AWS IAM password
// Initialize Kafka producer
$producer = new Producer($conf);
$topic = $producer->newTopic('your-topic-name'); // Change to your topic name
// Define the message
$key = 'example-key';
$value = 'example-value';
// Publish the message to Kafka
$topic->produce(RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA, 0, $value, $key);
// Wait for message to be delivered
$producer->flush(10000);
echo "Message published successfully.\n";
?>

I tried the above code without a username and password.

Try This,
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider;
use SimpleKafkaClient\Producer;
use SimpleKafkaClient\Configuration;

// Set up AWS credentials and region
$provider = CredentialProvider::defaultProvider();
$region = 'us-west-2'; // Change to your region

// Set up Kafka configuration
$conf = new Configuration();
$conf->set('metadata.broker.list', 'your-msk-broker-endpoints'); // Change to your broker list
$conf->set('sasl.mechanisms', 'AWS_MSK_IAM');
$conf->set('security.protocol', 'SASL_SSL');

// Add custom SASL configuration for AWS MSK IAM
$conf->set('sasl.aws_profile', 'default'); // or use 'sasl.aws_region' and 'sasl.aws_access_key_id'/'sasl.aws_secret_access_key'

// Initialize Kafka producer
$producer = new Producer($conf);
$topic = $producer->newTopic('your-topic-name'); // Change to your topic name

// Define the message
$key = 'example-key';
$value = 'example-value';

// Publish the message to Kafka
$topic->produce(RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA, 0, $value, $key);

// Wait for message to be delivered
$producer->flush(10000);

echo "Message published successfully.\n";
?>


Thank you for the sample, I am in process of trying, but was wondering where can I find documented the option you suggested as well as all the other configuration options (like sasl.mechanisms) I have only seen these in example code and never in documentation.  Thanks for help, much appreciated

apparently the base library under this one confluentinc/libkafka does not support IAM security only some forks.
